# How to reduce Python selenium Pyperclip.paste execution time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using following python script to copy contents from a local file and paste it into text-area, which actually works fine. However, it takes lots of time to complete this task, because my script types file contents to text-area one-by-one.

So I was looking if there is a way to modify following script so that it just paste complete data in one go.

```
import selenium
import pyperclip
path = 'path\to-my-file\Customer - Copy.txt'
fo = open(path, 'r').read()

#fo = fo.replace("\r","")
#fo = fo.replace("\n","")

pyperclip.copy(fo)
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chromedriver = 'path\to-my-file\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

import time 

time.sleep(10)

browser.get('http://example.com')

time.sleep(10)

username1 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ace_text-input")

username1.send_keys(pyperclip.paste())
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is solely *Task Automation* you could speed up the typing by writing a function and pass the *element* and the *text* setting the field directly with a script injection as follows :

```
def set_text(element, text):
  element._parent.execute_script("""
    var elm = arguments[0], text = arguments[1];
    if (!('value' in elm))
      throw new Error('Expected an <input> or <textarea>');
    elm.focus();
    elm.value = text;
    elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    """, element, text)
```

Comment: I am really new to JS and Py....is it possible to perform ctrl + v for an easier option, as I am performing Pyperclip.copy, so performing ctrl + v will be easy(not sure if it's possible)...or instead of send_keys there is any other option to perform Pyperclip.paste

Comment: Logically _Copy-Paste_ should work but then you have to write code for that where as _injecting a script_ would be much easier and faster option.

Comment: How to embed your script with my script(I have no idea, sorry)

Comment: Try to pass the _element (username1)_ and  _text ("foo...foo...foo")_ to the function `set_text(element, text)`

Answer (score 0):

This works (substitute COMMAND for Apple)....

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

ActionChains(driver) \
    .key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL) \
    .key_down('v') \
    .key_up('v') \
    .key_up(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL) \
    .perform()
```